# Better way to add values in a certain position of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, nested

Format of data given below:

```
a = [[0.65, 1148.59, 752.789], [0.65, 46.70, 30.5], ...]
```

I need to add 3rd position values , there are many values though. 
My solution:

```
total_values = []
for b in a:
   total_values.append(b[2])
# Now find sum(total_values).
```

I know this not a good practice. Is there any better way to get the total directly with out taking then into another list.

Comment: I tried sum() and it is working fine, but when I tried mean() instead of sum, it s not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression:

```
sum(val[2] for val in a)
```

Comment: I tried sum() and it is working fine, but when I tried mean() instead of sum, it s not working

Answer (score 0):

You can increment a sum variable rather than append to a new list:

```
total_sum = 0
for b in a:
   total_sum += b[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum(i[2] for i in a)`

Should solve that.

**Output:**

`783.289 # based on first 2 iteration given`

For `mean()`, you'll need to convert the generator back to a list first:

`numpy.mean([i[2] for i in a])`

Comment: I tried sum() and it is working fine, but when I tried mean() instead of sum, it s not working

Comment: You'll need to make the generator into a list first.  I've updated the answer.